# Read First Line of XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a `String` containing the text of an XML file. The string was formed from an input stream, but I don't think that's relevant.

The string seems okay, as:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("iString = " + iString);
```

outputs:

```
iString = <?xml version="1.0"?>
<DiagReport>
<LicensingData>
  <ToolVersion>6.3.94</ToolVersion>
  <LicensingStatus>SL_LICENSING_STATUS_NOTIFICATION</LicensingStatus>
</LicensingData>
</DiagReport>
```

I then convert the `String` to a `StringReader`

```
StringReader strReader = new StringReader(iString);
```

And the `StringReader` to an `XmlTextReader`

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(strReader);
```

Before even proceeding with my code, though, I want to check that the first node of the XML is `<DiagReport>`. Is there a way I can do that using the member functions of `XmlTextReader`?

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: Thanks! That actually realy helped with some other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.movetocontent.aspx

```
if (reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "DiagReport")
{
// Good to go
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Very neat and clean!

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through until you get the first element (which would be the root).

```
private string root = "";
while (reader.Read())
{
   //check if it's an element
   if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
   {
       //get the element name
       root = reader.Name;   

       //break out of this while loop as we only want the first element 
       break;
   }
}

if(root == "DiagReport")
{  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea. I just chose the other one because it's more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Just start reading from the reader.  It should be one of the first things you read so you can check then.  Otherwise just match a regex against the string before creating the reader.  However the reader isn't as heavyweight as a dom parser it's pretty much a wrapper around a sax parser so it processes the file incrementally.